# React component renders twice despite Strict mode being disabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have a specific component that renders twice. Basically, I am generating two random numbers and displaying them on the screen and for a split second, it shows undefined for both then shows the actual numbers. To test it further I did a simple console.log and it indeed logs it twice. So my question splits into two - 1. Why does the typography shows undefined for a split second before rendering? 2 - Why does it render twice?

Here's the related code:

Beginnging.js - this a counter that counts down from 3 and fires an RTK action, setting `gameStart` true.

```
function Beginning() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(3);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  useEffect(() => {
    countRef.current = count;
  }, [count]);

  const handleCount = () => {
    if (countRef.current === 1) {
      return setMessage("GO");
    }

    return setCount((count) => count - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleCount();
    }, 1000);

    if (message==='GO') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(start());
        
        
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count, message]);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h1" fontStyle={'Poppins'} fontSize={36}>GET READY...</Typography>

      <Typography fontSize={48} >{count}</Typography>
      <Typography fontSize={60} >{message}</Typography>
    </>
  );
}

export default Beginning;
```

AdditionMain.js - based on `gameStart`, this is where I render Beginning.js, once it counts down, MainInput is rendered.

```
const AdditionMain = () => {
  const gameStart = useSelector((state) => state.game.isStarted);
  const operation = "+";
  const calculation = generateNumbersAndResults().addition;


  if (!gameStart){
    
    return <Beginning/>
  }
    return (
      <>
        <MainInput operation={operation} calculation={calculation} />
      </>
    );
};

export default AdditionMain;
```

MainInput.js - the component in question.

```
const MainInput = ({ operation, calculation }) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [correctValue, setCorrectValue] = useState(false);
  const [calculatedNums, setCalculatedNums] = useState({});
  const [isIncorrect, setIsIncorrect] = useState(false);
  const [generateNewNumbers, setGenerateNewNumbers] = useState(false);
  const [haveToEnterAnswer, setHaveToEnterAnswer] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const seconds = useSelector((state) => state.game.seconds);
  const points = useSelector((state) => state.game.points);
  const lives = useSelector((state) => state.game.lives);

  const timerValid = seconds > 0;

  const newChallenge = () => {
    setIsIncorrect(false);
    setHaveToEnterAnswer(false);
    dispatch(restart());
  };

  const handleCount = () => {
    dispatch(loseTime());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (timerValid) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        handleCount();
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("first");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [timerValid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalculatedNums(calculation());
    setGenerateNewNumbers(false);
    setCorrectValue(false);
    setEnteredValue("");
  }, [generateNewNumbers]);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    if (correctValue) {
      setGenerateNewNumbers(true);
      dispatch(gainPoints());
      dispatch(gainTime());
    }

    if (+enteredValue === calculatedNums.result) {
      setCorrectValue(true);
    } else if (enteredValue.length === 0) {
      setHaveToEnterAnswer(true);
    } else {
      setIsIncorrect(true);
      dispatch(loseLife());
    }
  };

  const inputValueHandler = (value) => {
    setIsIncorrect(false);
    setHaveToEnterAnswer(false);
    setEnteredValue(value);
  };

  const submitOrTryNewOne = () => {
    return correctValue ? "Try new one" : "Submit";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {console.log("hello")}
      {seconds && lives > 0 ? (
        <>
          <GameInfo></GameInfo>

          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <Box
              sx={{
                marginTop: 8,
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <Typography>
                Fill in the box to make the equation true.
              </Typography>
              <Typography fontSize={28}>
                {operation !== "/"
                  ? `${calculatedNums.number1} ${operation} ${calculatedNums.number2}`
                  : `${calculatedNums.number2} ${operation} ${calculatedNums.number1}`}{" "}
                =
              </Typography>
              <TextField
                inputProps={{ inputMode: "numeric", pattern: "[0-9]*" }}
                type="number"
                name="sum"
                id="outlined-basic"
                label=""
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  inputValueHandler(event.target.value);
                }}
                disabled={correctValue}
                value={enteredValue}
              ></TextField>
              {haveToEnterAnswer && enterAnswer}
              {correctValue && correctAnswer}
              {isIncorrect && wrongAnswer}

              <Button
                type="button"
                sx={{ marginTop: 1 }}
                onClick={() => submitHandler()}
                variant="outlined"
              >
                {isIncorrect ? "Try again!" : submitOrTryNewOne()}
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Typography>GAME OVER</Typography>
          <Typography>Final Score: {points}</Typography>
          <Button onClick={newChallenge}>New Challenge</Button>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MainInput;
```

PS: I'm trying to figure out how to get this running on Codesandbox

Comment: Without a codesandbox it's hard to play around. Can you let us know which numbers are displaying as undefined, etc.? Easier than reading through everything and trying to figure out which ones aren't working.

Comment: so basicalli this line: ${calculatedNums.number1} ${operation} ${calculatedNums.number2} in MainInput.js. It reads as undefined + undefined above the input for split second, then actual numbers show up.

Comment: You can check your project in both development and production modes. If you can see still twice time render on the load time, your codes has a side effect. 
npm run build && serve build

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you render the page before the calculaed nums are established.

Try this instead. It will prevent the element from displaying until nums are generated.

```
const [calculatedNums, setCalculatedNums] = useState(null);

// This is down in your render area. Only render once calculatedNums are non-null.
{ calculatedNums &&
  <Typography fontSize={28}>
    operation !== "/"
      ? `${calculatedNums.number1} ${operation} ${calculatedNums.number2}`
      : `${calculatedNums.number2} ${operation} ${calculatedNums.number1}`}{" "}
      =
  </Typography>
}
```

In addition, you are probably generating your numbers twice, because you will generate new numbers on initial load, but then when you hit `setGenerateNewNumbers(true);` it will trigger a new calculation, which will then set the generatedNewNumbers to `false`, which will call the calc again, since it triggers whenever that state changes. It stops after that because it tries to set itself to false again and doesn't change.

You are changing a dependency value within the hook itself, causing it to run again. Without looking a lot more into your program flow, a really hacky way of fixing that would just be to wrap your `useEffect` operation inside an `if` check:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (generateNewNumbers === true) {
    //All your stuff here.
  }
}, [generateNewNumbers]
```

That way, it won't run again when you set it to false.